# How to include extra applications in packages created with quickly?

Tags: quickly

The application I'm developing using Quickly would benefit from nautilus extension I'm planning on writing for the occasion. The question is: how do I tell quickly to include this extension in the final package, and how do I specify the right location to install this extension to?

Comment: @tachyons your comment leads to the conclusion that I must develop the nautilus extension as a separate application, and then set the dependency accordingly on the main app. Of course this could solve my problem, but this is not the solution I'm looking for. I really want the nautilus extension to be *shipped* with the main app.

Comment: Do you know which folder you want the extension files to end up in?

Comment: @fluteflute I guess so. In this particular case the extension is targeted to the last development series of nautilus, and there are of course well defined locations (local and system-wide) for its extensions.

Comment: As the nautilus extension in question is not in the standard repositories, I vote to repoen tachyons question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `quickly configure dependencies <dependency>`